# Canvas Line Rendering Issue in Windows Chrome

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, canvas

I draw a list of points produced with `pointerMove` events using the following code:

```js
const pointList = JSON.parse(
  '[{"x":648.666748046875,"y":393.66668701171875},{"x":651.3333740234375,"y":394.3333435058594},{"x":652,"y":395},{"x":652.666748046875,"y":395},{"x":654.666748046875,"y":395},{"x":656,"y":395},{"x":659.3333740234375,"y":391.66668701171875},{"x":663.3333740234375,"y":388.3333435058594},{"x":664.666748046875,"y":387},{"x":665.3333740234375,"y":384.3333435058594},{"x":668,"y":381},{"x":668.666748046875,"y":379.66668701171875},{"x":670.666748046875,"y":376.3333435058594},{"x":672,"y":374.3333435058594},{"x":672.666748046875,"y":373},{"x":673.3333740234375,"y":371},{"x":674.6666870117188,"y":369.66668701171875},{"x":675.3333740234375,"y":367},{"x":676,"y":365.66668701171875},{"x":676.6666870117188,"y":363},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":359.66668701171875},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":357.66668701171875},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":354.3333435058594},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":351.66668701171875},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":348.3333435058594},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":346.3333435058594},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":343},{"x":678.6666870117188,"y":341},{"x":678,"y":339},{"x":678,"y":335},{"x":677.3333740234375,"y":331.66668701171875},{"x":676.6666870117188,"y":327.66668701171875},{"x":674.6666870117188,"y":324.3333435058594},{"x":674,"y":319.66668701171875}]'
);

const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

ctx.setTransform(new DOMMatrix().translate(-600, -300));

ctx.beginPath();
pointList.forEach((p, i) => {
  if (i === 0) {
    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    return;
  }
  ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
});
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border: 1px solid grey"></canvas>
```

[Codesandbox demo](https://4ndvx6.csb.app/)

I notice there is a subtle gap in the rendered line.
[image: Subtle gap image]

I wonder if this is a bug in Chrome 121.0.6167.140 in Windows 11 because this issue does not occur in Firefox.
Even the rendering engine used is different, such output is somewhat unexpected.
Or do I miss something fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Well, it actually looks okay on my laptop (Macbook Air M1 Sonoma 14 Chrome 121)